# Pattern synonyms deriving read?

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

Pattern synonyms provide a shorthand way to express a value; also they can provide an abstract name to avoid a client module breaking into the data decl. Here's a not very useful one, as an example for discussion:

```
data MyNum = MkNum Int

pattern Zero :: MyNum
pattern Zero = MkNum 0
```

What I can do to help data capture is provide a `Read` instance for `MyNum`. How do I get a `Read` instance for `Zero`? (`Zero` is a pseudo-data constructor, *not* a type constructor, so that question is making a category error.)

All I can think of is to avoid `deriving (Read, ...)` for `MyNum` and then hand-craft

```
instance Read MyNum where
  ... parse "MkNum ..."
  ... parse "Zero"
```

For parsing, `Zero` should be just another constructor for `MyNum`. It could be derived -- or could it?

I don't think any of the advanced deriving mechanisms would help here. Because the type is `MyNum` and the only associated constructor ie `MkNum`.

I could provide a function `readZero :: String -> MyNum`. But I can't overload `read`, therefore I can't embed `Zero` inside a long String literal that I'm reading to make a data structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think a problem is that people can declare such patterns in *different files*: files that *use* your module. So that would mean that the implementation of `parse` could vary depending on what libraries the user loads. This is typically a dynamism that most programmers do not like.

Comment: Yes. Let's keep it simple and assume the pattern is defined in the same module as the data type.

Comment: I don't know of any auto-deriving tools that can do this. The only option I see is to define your own `Read MyNum` instance and overload `readsPrec` accordingly. (`read` will then work, since it is a library function calling `readsPrec`)

Comment: You could hack up something with Template Haskell, probably.